# Update value from regex substr

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to clear a text value and then update it.

In table `tbl_input`, the column `txt_input` contain a text that I split at `chr(10) | chr(13)` to get all the lines.

Then I clean the text by removing what line I don't want with a `NOT EXISTS`

But at the end, how I can update `tbl_input(txt_input)` with the text value that I clean ? I need to concatenate each line with `chr(10) | chr(13)`.

```
WITH cte (txt) AS
(
     SELECT txt_input txt
     FROM tbl_input
     WHERE id_input = 177364564
) ,
cte_remove (t) AS (
     SELECT 'remove test' from dual
)
SELECT txt_value 
FROM (SELECT trim(replace(replace(txt, chr(10), ''), chr(13), '')) txt
      FROM (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(txt, '^.*$', 1, level, 'm') txt
            FROM cte
            CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(txt, '^.*$', 1, level, 'm') IS NOT NULL
      ) sr
) sr2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM cte_remove r 
      WHERE lower(r.t) = lower(sr2.txt))
```

For exemple :

Table `tbl_input` :

```
id_input = 1
txt_input = aaaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

If I add **ccc** on the `cte_remove`, after update I would like to get the value below in my `txt_input` column for my current id :

```
aaaa
bbb
ddd
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify what you are asking.

Comment: I added the sample data

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way of doing it, adapt to your original table, and I give the select on, rewrite it for an update (I did not try to optimize it):

```
    WITH cte (txt) AS
(
     SELECT 'aaaa'||chr(10)||chr(13)||'bbb'
||chr(10)||chr(13)||'ccc'
||chr(10)||chr(13)||'ddd' txt_value
     FROM dual
) ,
cte_remove (t) AS (
     SELECT 'ccc' from dual
)
SELECT listagg(txt,chr(10)||chr(13)) within group (order by lv) res
FROM (SELECT trim(replace(replace(txt, chr(10), ''), chr(13), '')) txt, lv
      FROM (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(txt, '^.*$', 1, level, 'm') txt, level lv
            FROM cte
            CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(txt, '^.*$', 1, level, 'm') IS NOT NULL
      ) sr
) sr2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM cte_remove r 
      WHERE lower(r.t) = lower(sr2.txt))
/
    RES
    ----
    aaaa
    
    bbb
    
    ddd
```

Answer (score 1):

If the text you want to remove does not have any characters with special meaning in regular expressions then you can simply use:

```sql
UPDATE tbl_input
SET txt_input = REGEXP_REPLACE(
                  txt_input,
                  '(^|'||CHR(13)||CHR(10)||')remove test($|'||CHR(13)||CHR(10)||')',
                  '\1',
                  1,
                  0,
                  'ni'
                )
WHERE id_input = 177364564
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl_input ( id_input INT, txt_input VARCHAR2(200) );

INSERT INTO tbl_input ( id_input, txt_input )
SELECT 177364564,
       'aaa'||CHR(13)||CHR(10)
       ||'bbb'||CHR(13)||CHR(10)
       ||'ccc'||CHR(13)||CHR(10)
       ||'remove test'||CHR(13)||CHR(10)
       ||'ddd'
FROM   DUAL;
```

Then, after the update:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tbl_input;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> |ID_INPUT |TXT_INPUT|
> |---------|---------|
> |177364564|aaa      |
> |         |bbb      |
> |         |ccc      |
> |         |ddd      |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d4a61419f0a83c5883aadb78964f81bd)*

Answer (score 1):

`WITH` goes to a subquery selecting a new value

```
UPDATE tbl_input t
SET  txt_input = (
         WITH cte_remove (t) AS (
              SELECT 'CCc' from dual
         )
         SELECT listagg(txt, chr(13)||chr(10)) newval
         FROM (SELECT t, trim(replace(replace(txt, chr(10), ''), chr(13), '')) txt
               FROM (SELECT t, REGEXP_SUBSTR(txt_input, '^.*$', 1, level, 'm') txt
                     FROM (SELECT txt_input, lower(cte_remove.t) t 
                           FROM cte_remove)
                     CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(txt_input, '^.*$', 1, level, 'm') IS NOT NULL
               )
         )
         WHERE lower(txt) != t
      )
```

This will work only for a single row in `cte_remove`.
For multiple strings to be excluded use original  `NOT EXISTS`.

```
UPDATE tbl_input t
SET  txt_input = (
      WITH cte_remove (t) AS (
           SELECT 'CCc' from dual union all
           SELECT 'bBb' from dual
      )
      SELECT listagg(txt, chr(13)||chr(10)) newval
      FROM (SELECT trim(replace(replace(txt, chr(10), ''), chr(13), '')) txt
            FROM (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(txt_input, '^.*$', 1, level, 'm') txt
                  FROM (SELECT txt_input FROM DUAL) 
                  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(txt_input, '^.*$', 1, level, 'm') IS NOT NULL
            ) sr
      ) sr2
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM cte_remove r 
            WHERE lower(r.t) = lower(sr2.txt))         
 );
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=31df7e7a48bd9608f1b190156916b206)

Comment: I have around 2500 lines in my cte_remove, I got the error "ORA-01489: string concatenation result too long" when I execute it